# Missing X-axis labels in R linegraph

Tags: r, plot, axis, axis-labels, linegraph

I'm trying to get the x-axis to display every x label (i.e. every year) but R automatically omits some of them. How do I solve this?

```
years = c(1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989, 1990, 1991,
          1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 2000, 2001, 2003, 2005, 2008,
          2012, 2014, 2015, 2016)

abundance = c(308, 53, 43, 59, 74, 320, 29, 1237, 88, 73,
              66, 21, 15, 61, 70, 39, 60, 27, 3, 73, 23)

plot(x=years, y=abundance, type="l", xlab="Years", ylab="Total Abundance", las = 2)
```

Comment: `plot(..., xaxp = c(range(years), diff(range(years))))` would also work

Comment: So this actually gives me every single year from 1984 to 2016 on the x-axis, when there are actually years that are left out from that range (i.e. 1992, 1993, 1994, 2002 etc). Is there a way to leave these points out?

Comment: you have to turn off the axes and manually set them like the (now deleted) answer below showed. the linked question and answer are also an example